Mushy water-logged front yard, aerate?
New house and part of our front yard stays very wet (Pacific North West so raining a lot now). It's very squishy and leaves big marks when you walk over it. Previous owners told me that that happens and suggested that the soil might be a heavy clay. Picture below:

Outside of a bigger project like installing a french drain or something, would aerating the soil here likely improve the situation? Or is that a fix with a low likelihood of working?

I assume PNW = Pacific North West?

Apologies. Yes, that is correct.

Can you add peat and sand in the Spring? What about dolomite spaded in to lighten the clay? Adds calcium without making it alkaline. Roses actually like clay.

Aerating at the proper time (not now with it sodden so the holes would just glaze over - a some point when the yard has dried out, but is not rock-hard) might help a little bit. It won't help much if the soil is clay for a depth considerably deeper than the aeration holes reach. But it's better than not doing it, or doing it at the wrong time.
In many cases part of the problem is the grading of the surface - it's best to maintain at least 1/8" per foot (1%) grade to a place the surface water can drain away to.

Thanks. Yes, I'm not sure how far the clay goes. There might be that level of grade already, but I'm not entirely sure.

Best time to Aerate your lawn is in Late of summer or just shy warm Autumn (August-October) This gives lawn time adapt to inevitable winter dormancy. If you live however in a sub-Tropical climate you can do virtually any time of the year, preferably early Spring so Grass has time to regenerate. Holes dug via aeration should be refilled with a 50/50 mixture of Compost/Sand refered to in Golf industry as "Lawn leveling" mix.
While a French drain is certainly good in a pinch, Idea is to retain much water for slow release as possible. One scenario is possibly installing a rain garden. A planted depression, designed with engineered soil mix to absorb maximum potential of rain that falls into it. Invented in Maryland in Early 90s they surged in popularity in Pacific States like Washington/Oregon because high rain fall unslowed to mitigate flood risk, improve water quality especially in areas near drainage rivers/creeks.

And growing popularity in Western, dry states to alleviate drought by regenerating underground water supply.
